# How can you gamify the recruitment of new employees?

Tags: io-psychology, gamification

We recently had a user on our site ask if they could add game mechanics to their employee recruitment. To be honest, I'm having a little trouble finding solutions for this. I'd really appreciate any insight you guys might have.

I guess my first question is, who would you incentivize for this, and how? Are there any case studies that cover a scenario like this?

Comment: What kind of company are they?

Comment: I have read one study about this in the past. The results were not promising, since the game mechanics in recruitment have to account for abstract qualities in individuals which is hard to do, with any degree of accuracy to be able to rank potential hires. Moreover, the qualities vary with position making it an extremely complicated process.

Comment: ^^Well said. These are the objections I have as well. I was hoping that there was something I wasn't thinking of. I appreciate your insight, thanks.

Comment: @AsheeshR: I think this is a good answer. Why not post it as one.

Comment: @kdzia Without *reference* to the actual study, its just an opinion, not an answer. If I find the study I had read, I will surely post it as an answer.

Comment: That's right, of course. I assumed you had the study at hand - my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to work on stimulating rejected candidates to become referrals.

Every candidate who has been rejected is already quite well into what the job is all about. S/he should be very good at explaining the job requirements. (The pitfall of the majority of job ads, IMHO is that they bitterly fail at explaining what the job is about.)

At the same time rejected candidates must be likely to know colleagues good for that job. And it is in their self-interest to promote those colleagues, because they would have less competition for all the other vacancies.